# A substitute for Hydrangeas that can tolerate full sun (zone 8b)

Tags: plant-recommendations

I have an artificial border against a driveway which has limited depth (about 20-30cm, 8"-12"); I wanted a line of plants with good volume (perhaps 1m/yd plus in height) and some nice colour, so Hydrangeas would have been ideal. Unfortunately, the drive gets the full sun in the afternoon and after a short trial and some hot weather it seemed unlikely they would last, so I transplanted them to more shaded locations.

Now I am looking for a replacement, but I don't really have an idea what would have the right combination: relatively shallow roots, about 1m in height, nice colours, tolerant of full sun and low maintenance.

The location is Brussels which is apparently zone 8b. The soil is quite heavy but I can mix in some compost if necessary. I am not sure how it drains. The border has a wall on one side and a concrete bottom at least, so it could be sealed, but on the other hand, the soil seems relatively dry.

Comment: When you say 'artificial border' does that mean a container with drainage holes, or does it mean soil piled up on something with no drainage to make a border?

Comment: I mean on one side there is a wall and it appears to be concrete underneath (maybe part of the foundations) and probably on the other side as well, so there is limited space for root growth (though I can't be sure there isn't a gap somewhere). It is about 40cm/16" wide, and a few metres/yards long. I haven't lived in the house long to say how or if it drains.

Answer (score 2):

[Spirea](http://www.firsteditionsplants.com/the-plants/highlighted-collections/spirea) sounds like the perfect fit. Lots of options, but generally love full sun, handle hardscapes nearby, and are OK with drying out a bit.